# c# search result without file extension

Tags: c#, winforms, search

I need to hide the file extensions(.jpg, .exe) on the search result show in listbox. Can someone help me with this? Here are my codes. I have textbox, button and listbox.

button1 code: this code search the word on my textbox on the path specified and show it on listbox1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    x = 0;
    var path = "C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\FLASH\\SEARCH";
    listBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + textBox1.Text + "*")
        .Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f)).ToList();
}
```

listbox1 code: this code run the search result on click:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = listBox1.SelectedItem as string;
    if (fileName != null)
    {
        var path = Path.Combine("C:\\Users\\thesis\\Desktop\\THESIS\\FLASH\\SEARCH", fileName);

        if (x != 0)
        {
            Process.Start(path);
        } 
    }
    x += 1;
}
```

With this codes my output is like this: "result.exe" "result.jpg". What I need as an output is like this: "result", "output".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use [`GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            x = 0;
            var path = "C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\FLASH\\SEARCH";
            listBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + textBox1.Text + "*")
                               .Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
                               .ToList();
        }
```

Comment: It's ok. It is impossible to know everything.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath)
```

to retrieve file names without their extensions. Your query will look like:

```
listBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + textBox1.Text + "*")
                               .Select(f => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f))
                               .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
    var liist = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*" + textBox1.Text + "*")
                         .Select(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();
```